# Paired sign test with weighting

Tags: r, survey, weighted, weighting, pairwise.wilcox.test

In R, I am using the `survey` package to conduct these tests on paired data:

- Weighted Wilcoxon Signed Rank test
- Weighted Sign test

However, I am struggling in doing them.

By defining a design and then using the functions

```
signed_rank<-function (x) {sign(x) * rank(abs(x))}
summary (svyglm(signed_rank(variable) ~ 1, mydesign))
```

I have been able to conduct a non-paired wilcoxon.

But I have not been able to conduct the paired version as well as the Sign test. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: This is a cross-post of a question answered on CrossValidated, where it is more appropriate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613027/paired-sign-and-wilcoxon-tests-with-weighting/613164